# How to calculate the tangent angle with the axis of an ellipse

Tags: calculus

I hava an ellipse. I know its' equation.

[image]

For a given 't' how can I calculate angle "alpha". (I also know the coordinate of the tangent point)

Comment: Do you know what a derivative is and what it represents? what have you tried?

Comment: "Ellipsis" is a term used in typography and in rhetoric.  It doesn't mean the same thing as "ellipse".  I changed it.

Comment: I have the basic understanding of calculus. But I am lack of Geometric knowledge. Can you give me some directions?

Comment: Hint: $(\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt})$ is a tangent vector at $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tangent is in the direction of 
$$\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t},\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)$$
Then the slope of the tangent is given by
$$\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}}=\frac{10\cos{t}}{-30\sin{t}}=-\frac{1}{3}\cot{t}$$

The angle is the $\arctan$ of the slope